# Access controls on User Control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I have a user control, and I need to access a label on that user control from another Window.. example... simply change the text of a label. Example..

```
Usercontrol.label1.content = "Got it"
```

I can access any control on the MainWindow by doing the following:

```
Public main As MainWindow = DirectCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow)
```

How do I do this for a User Control in WPF?

Comment: You don't need to "access" any label anywhere. Use a viewmodel and bind it's properties appropriately in the XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access MainWindow:

```
Dim Main = TryCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow);
```

If your UserControl defined statically like this:

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="uc" />
```

You can just use it's name like: `Main.uc.label1.Text = "Hello World"`

**If your UserControl is dynamically added to a container, try following:**

If your UserControl is in a Border:

```
Dim control = Main.MyBorder.Child as MyUserControl
control.label1.Text = "Hello World"
```

If there are multiple UserControls in your container such as (StackPanel/Grid/Wrappanel etc):

```
Dim controls = Main.MyStackPanel.Childern.OfType(Of MyUserControl)()
For Each control In controls
    control.label1.Text = "Hello World"
Next
```

Even though you can get the exact UserControl you want by checking the variables it has!

```
Dim control = Main.MyStackPanel.Childern.OfType(Of MyUserControl)().Where(Function(x) x.label1.Text = "myLabel").FirstOrDefault() 
//You can access any variable that exists in your UserControl by 'x'
control.label1.Text = "Hello World"
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you have got a reference to the window in which the `UserControl` resides, you could access it using this reference.

So if the `UserControl` is for example defined in a window called `Window1`, here is how you could access it from another window:

```
Dim window1 As Window1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of Window1).FirstOrDefault()
window1.uc.label1.Text = "1"
```

This of course assumes that there is a `Window1` opened and visible on the screen and that you given the `UserControl` element an `x:Name` in the XAML markup of the window:

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="uc" />
```